# Read a SqlCommand column (multiple rows) into a single C# byte[] array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sqlcommand

Given a SQL table `Document` with data:

```
ID  Content     ByteLength  Sequence
1   Part1...    945669      1
1   Part2...    945669      2
1   Part3...    945669      3

...

2   Part1...    45234       1
2   Part2...    45234       2
```

Where:

```
Document.Content = Up to 32KB of data
Document.ByteLength = Total data in bytes for the Document ID
Document.Sequence = Order of content in the Document ID
```

How can I read all of `Document.Content` into a single byte array `byte[] Content`?

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Content FROM Document WHERE ID=1 ORDER BY Sequence", connection))
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // What goes here?

            // if we just want one row:
            //var fileBytes = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0); // read the file data from the selected row (first column in above query)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can write in append mode to a binary file. What is the datatype of the Content field?

Comment: The first 3 sequences are all 1, should they not be 1,2,3 ?

Comment: @Steve Currently varchar(max). It mostly holds RTF and txt content.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes you're right! Have fixed.

Comment: File.AppendAllText inside the loop and when you have finished the loop ReadAllText

Comment: The approach depends on what you're looking for. If it's ok to keep all the data in memory just declare a list outside the loop and append to it. Is there a reason you work with byte arrays when the column contains strings?

Comment: You could just write into a MemoryStream within the loop then ToArray() when your done.

Comment: I do not want to read/write the file content to disk. Most of the files are very small (<32k) and I need a solution for the occasional large file in the database. Fine to keep it in memory. I am working with byte arrays as the Content column contains strings of RTF data and I need to process that data through a document conversion assembly which expects to receive either a `byte[]` array or a filepath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that this *Content* field contains text data, you can simply use a StringBuilder to add data while you read the content field

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Content FROM Document WHERE ID=1 ORDER BY Sequence", connection))
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // Set a large enough initial capacity
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32767);
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        sb.Append(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

Now, at the loop exit, all the content is in the StringBuilder buffer and you can get it back in a byte array with

```
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: There is a (byte[]) cast from the reader in the current code so I think it must var/binary

Comment: The OP stated in the comment above that Content is a varchar(max) field